# XSL Grouping with 1.0

Tags: xslt, xpath, key, grouping

I have an XML  like following.

```
<Doc>
<row>
  <Col1>13820PKS-</Col1> 
  <Col6>01</Col6> 
  <Col9>1507462800</Col9> 
  <Col12>15074628</Col12> 
  <Col14>4</Col14> 
  </row>
<row>
  <Col1>13820PKS-</Col1> 
  <Col6>01</Col6> 
  <Col9>1507462800</Col9> 
  <Col12>15074629</Col12> 
  <Col14>5</Col14> 
  </row>
 <row>
  <Col1>13820PKS-</Col1> 
  <Col6>01</Col6> 
  <Col9>1808502801</Col9> 
  <Col12>18085021</Col12> 
  <Col14>1</Col14> 
  </row>
 <row>
  <Col1>13820PKS-</Col1> 
  <Col6>02</Col6> 
  <Col9>2710004100</Col9> 
  <Col12>2710004100</Col12> 
  <Col14>1</Col14> 
  </row>
</Doc>
```

The Document actually has more than 2000 rows.
The end result should be

```
<Doc>
    <ListID id="01">
        <MainArt>
            <ItemCode>13820PKS-</ItemCode>
            <List>
                <SubArt>
                    <ItemCode>1507462800</ItemCode>
                    <SubArtList>
                        <row>
                            <ItemCode>15074628</ItemCode>
                            <Quantity>4</Quantity>
                        </row>
                        <row>
                            <ItemCode>15074629</ItemCode>
                            <Quantity>5</Quantity>
                        </row>
                    </SubArtList>
                </SubArt>
                <SubArt>
                    <ItemCode>1808502801</ItemCode>
                    <SubArtList>
                        <row>
                            <ItemCode>18085021</ItemCode>
                            <Quantity>1</Quantity>
                        </row>
                    </SubArtList>
                </SubArt>
            </List>
        </MainArt>
    </ListID>
    <ListID id="02">
        <MainArt>
            <ItemCode>13820PKS-</ItemCode>
            <List>
                <SubArt>
                    <ItemCode>2710004100</ItemCode>
                    <SubArtList>
                        <row>
                            <ItemCode>2710004100</ItemCode>
                            <Quantity>1</Quantity>
                        </row>
                    </SubArtList>
                </SubArt>
            </List>
        </MainArt>
    </ListID>
</Doc>
```

I am still in my learning Phase and don't really have the skills to use templates. I tried to do it with recursive for-each Loop but that also didn't work. 
Any Help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to group the rows by Col6?

Comment: In XSLT 1.0 you'll need to use a technique called Muenchian Grouping (http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html) which may make your brain hurt the first time you see it, but is the best way! Could you possible amend your question to show the actual expected output for your given input, as it looks like you may need to do multiple grouping here. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for your response. I know the Muenchian Grouping method (with Know means I read about it) but as you said it makes my brain hurt :).

Comment: I am still learning how to implement templates and I think without understanding the template implementation, I will not be able to understand the "Muenchian Grouping".  I have to do multiple grouping. Col12 and Col14 comes under Col9 which comes under Col1 which comes under Col6. Its a bit complicated I know. The second part is the expected output.

Comment: The second part shows the structure of the expected output, but is not the actual output you are literally expecting, I believe? So, if you could show the actual output for your current input, that would help alot. Thanks!

Comment: I changed the input and expected output. Sorry for the "not so clear" output. I think now it should be easy to understand what I want to achieve here. Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not making it easy in yourself with having three levels of multiple grouping! But here is what you do...

To start with, you are grouping by **Col6** elements at the very top level, so you define a key to look up your **row** elements by their **Col6** value.

```
<xsl:key name="Col6" match="row" use="Col6"/>
```

So, for a given value, the key will return all **row** elements where the **Col6** element is equal to that value.

Now, to get the 'distinct' **Col6** values, what happens is that you look at all **row** elements, but pick out only the ones which occur first in the group for the **Col6** key. This is done like so,

```
<xsl:apply-templates 
     select="row[generate-id() = generate-id(key('Col6', Col6)[1])]" 
     mode="Col6" />
```

(Note the use of **mode** here, because the final XSLT will have multiple templates matching **row** elements, so you will need to distinguish between them).

Now, within the template that matches the **row** element for **Col6**, you then need to group by **Col1** elements. This is where it gets slightly trickier, because you will need to define a key that is a combination of both **Col6** and **Col1** elements. (To allow for two **Col1** elements that may have different **Col6** values)

```
<xsl:key name="Col1" match="row" use="concat(Col6, '|', Col1)"/>
```

Note the use of the pipe `|` character to separate the values. This can be any character, just as long as it doesn't occur in either **Col6** or **Col1**

Then to get the distinct **Col1** elements within the current **Col6**, you would do this

```
<xsl:apply-templates 
     select="key('Col6', Col6)
             [generate-id() = generate-id(key('Col1', concat(Col6, '|', Col1))[1])]"
     mode="Col1" />
```

Finally, for your **Col9** element, you would have a triply concatenated key.

```
<xsl:key name="Col9" match="row" use="concat(Col6, '|', Col1, '|', Col9)"/>
```

This could be used in a similar manner to get all the **Col9** elements within the current **Col1**.

Putting this altogether, gives the following XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:key name="Col6" match="row" use="Col6"/>
  <xsl:key name="Col1" match="row" use="concat(Col6, '|', Col1)"/>
  <xsl:key name="Col9" match="row" use="concat(Col6, '|', Col1, '|', Col9)"/>

  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="row[generate-id() = generate-id(key('Col6', Col6)[1])]" mode="Col6" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="row" mode="Col6">
    <ListID id="{Col6}">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="key('Col6', Col6)[generate-id() = generate-id(key('Col1', concat(Col6, '|', Col1))[1])]" mode="Col1" />
    </ListID>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="row" mode="Col1">
    <MainArt>
      <ItemCode>
        <xsl:value-of select="Col1"/>
      </ItemCode>
      <List>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="key('Col1', concat(Col6, '|', Col1))[generate-id() = generate-id(key('Col9', concat(Col6, '|', Col1, '|', Col9))[1])]" mode="Col9" />
      </List>
    </MainArt>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="row" mode="Col9">
    <SubArt>
      <ItemCode>
        <xsl:value-of select="Col9"/>
      </ItemCode>
      <SubArtList>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="key('Col9', concat(Col6, '|', Col1, '|', Col9))" mode="Col12" />
      </SubArtList>
    </SubArt>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="row" mode="Col12">
    <row>
      <ItemCode>
        <xsl:value-of select="Col12"/>
      </ItemCode>
      <Quantity>
        <xsl:value-of select="Col14"/>
      </Quantity>
    </row>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to your sample XML, the following is output

```
<Doc>
  <ListID id="01">
    <MainArt>
      <ItemCode>13820PKS-</ItemCode>
      <List>
        <SubArt>
          <ItemCode>1507462800</ItemCode>
          <SubArtList>
            <row>
              <ItemCode>15074628</ItemCode>
              <Quantity>4</Quantity>
            </row>
            <row>
              <ItemCode>15074629</ItemCode>
              <Quantity>5</Quantity>
            </row>
          </SubArtList>
        </SubArt>
        <SubArt>
          <ItemCode>1808502801</ItemCode>
          <SubArtList>
            <row>
              <ItemCode>18085021</ItemCode>
              <Quantity>1</Quantity>
            </row>
          </SubArtList>
        </SubArt>
      </List>
    </MainArt>
  </ListID>
  <ListID id="02">
    <MainArt>
      <ItemCode>13820PKS-</ItemCode>
      <List>
        <SubArt>
          <ItemCode>2710004100</ItemCode>
          <SubArtList>
            <row>
              <ItemCode>2710004100</ItemCode>
              <Quantity>1</Quantity>
            </row>
          </SubArtList>
        </SubArt>
      </List>
    </MainArt>
  </ListID>
</Doc>
```

Comment: Thank you. It worked as I wanted and Thank you for the detailed explanation. I really appreciate it.